# For C++ ranges::find_first_of(r1,r2), what is the location of the match in the second range?

Tags: c++

[C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) has [find_first_of()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/algorithm/find_first_of):

```
result = ranges::find_first_of(r1, r2)
```

Using `*result` I can identify the value of the first item in r1 which is also in r2.

I am only interested in the locations of the match in r1 and r2. So, if `std::distance(r1.begin(), result)` provides that info for `r1`, what about for `r2`?

Comment: fwiw, also the non-ranges `find_first_of` only returns an iterator to the first range

Comment: Yes, @formerlyknownas_463035818, but the ranges version looks to much better.

Comment: sure, its just suggesting that `find_first_of` isnt the right function to call in this case. I mean you can use `find_first_of` and then another `find`, but I cannot believe that there isnt something better, also considering that if you look at the [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) both iterators could be returned for no extra cost

Comment: The cppreference you've linked clearly states that the return value is: _Iterator to the first element in the range [first1, last1)(...)_ Why doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: Using `find_first_of` will not give you the necessary information (you would have to call `find` on the second ranger after that). I also don't see another stl algorithm that does what you want to do. So the only way other than calling `find` in the aftermath I see without doing very abusive stuff (think a global variable set in the predicate) is to write your own function that returns both iterators. As already noted, adapting the possible implementation should be pretty easy.